# How do I get different colors for directories, etc. in iTerm2?

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, iterm

I have a new MacBookPro, and I installed the latest release of iTerm2.

Even after I imported various color schemes, I notice that they just change the color of the text and background only.

What I was expecting to see were different colors for files VS directories, VS hidden files, etc etc. How do I do that on iTerm2?

A related question is how do I actually *specify* what I want the colors of directories, files, etc to be?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing color of folders, files, execs on iTerm2](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/258406/changing-color-of-folders-files-execs-on-iterm2)

Comment: Thanks @JohnN, that helped, but please see my edit.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You have to do two things:

- set the `LSCOLORS` environment variable
- create an alias for `ls` so that it shows colors by default

If you are using Zsh - starting with Catalina it's the default shell, see [MacOs Terminal zsh - cannot use ansi](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/396293/119271). Otherwise for Bash edit `~/.bash_profile`  and add the following:

```
export LSCOLORS="EHfxcxdxBxegecabagacad" 

alias ls='ls -lGH'        <-----This shows in list format, follow symlinks colorized
```

The the colors are set by each bit above; the first being foreground and the second being background.   The first two characters refer to directories having a bold blue foreground and a light grey background.

However, there's a great online utility to see what each of the colors mean and look like in real time.  It will even generate the "code" for you.  (I am not affiliated with this at all).  It will work in both MacOS/FreeBSD and Linux.  Make sure you select the BSD option for macOS.

[LSCOLORS Calculator](https://geoff.greer.fm/lscolors/)

---

The order of the attributes are as follows:

```
1.   directory
2.   symbolic link
3.   socket
4.   pipe
5.   executable
6.   block special
7.   character special
8.   executable with setuid bit set
9.   executable with setgid bit set
10.   directory writable to others, with sticky bit
11.   directory writable to others, without sticky
```

The color designators are as follows:

```
a    black
b    red
c    green
d    brown
e    blue
f    magenta
g    cyan
h    light grey
A    bold black, usually shows up as dark grey
B    bold red
C    bold green
D    bold brown, usually shows up as yellow
E    bold blue
F    bold magenta
G    bold cyan
H    bold light grey; looks like bright white
x    default foreground or background
```

Comment: Hi Allan, thanks! A couple questions, can you explain some more about i) Why I have to put it in .bash_profile and not say, the .zshrc I think it was, and ii) a little bit more about the export LSCOLORS part? Do I go to that site you mentioned and set my color scheme from there? How does this jive then with the color schemes of iterm2? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps this is what is confusing me: I am using iterm2. What does this mean for which file we change? (.bash_profile VS .zshrc)? For what it's worth, on this new machine I currently have neither...

Comment: Ah, ok, the echo shows `bash`. So I should make a new ~/.bash_profile I am guessing since none exists.

Comment: I had to edit ~/.zprofile on a '21 MacBook Pro, as bash_profile isn't sourced for new terminals.

Comment: The following LSCOLORS string works well for me on a "Homebrew" themed Terminal.app tab with a black bg, yellow fg: "GxFxeHbHcxegecabagacad" = bold cyan directories, bold magenta symlinks, green executables, blue-on-white sockets, red-on-white pipes. The main win here is fixing that default dark blue directory color which is tough to read on a black bg.

Answer (score 21):

Open bash_profile using command:

```
open ~/.bash_profile
```

and add the following lines:

```
export PS1="\[\033[36m\]\u\[\033[m\]@\[\033[32m\]\h:\[\033[33;1m\]\w\[\033[m\]\$ "
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=ExFxBxDxCxegedabagacad
alias ls='ls -GFh'
```

then source bash_profile using:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: KayV what does this do exactly? Can you expand please?

Comment: Thanks. This was what I was looking for my macbook. Best solution for coloring directories differently from files.

Comment: I found in zsh that the PS1 line just changed my terminal to that string.

Comment: This works but now my terminal prompt starts with `(base) \[\033[36m\]\u\[\033[m\]@\[\033[32m\]\h:\[\033[33;1m\]\w\[\033[m\]$`

Answer (score 10):

For anyone using **zsh**, this is what I was able to do on my machine to get it to work:

**1. Create the .zshrc file**

`touch .zshrc`

**2. Add these to the file**

```
PS1="%{%F{033}%}%n%{%f%}@%{%F{green}%}%m:%{%F{yellow}%}%~%{$%f%}%  "
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=ExFxBxDxCxegedabagacad
```

**3. Restart iTerm2**

Will produce a terminal that looks like this

[image: Picture of my terminal with colors on for example]

I was able to get this thanks to the different answers in this thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689765/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-my-prompt-in-zsh-different-from-normal-text#2534676

Higly recommend the thread to learn more on how the customizations work

Comment: this looks good

Comment: This is perfect.

Comment: You don't need to restart iTerm2 to use these, just open a new tab in iTerm2, or type `source ~/.zshrc`

Comment: worked for me well, Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

An alternative to `LSCOLORS` is [GRC (the GeneRic Colouriser)](https://github.com/garabik/grc),  which can be used with pretty much any command-line app, not just `ls`.

If you've got Homebrew installed, install `grc` with `brew install grc` -
 this will set up aliases automatically, including for `ls`. It comes with aliases and config files for many different commands, and it's (relatively) trivial to hack a config file using Python regular expressions for any command that `grc` doesn't currently cover (`tmutil` and `launchctl`, for example).

(I was going to add this to the question I flagged as a possible dupe, but with your edit it's probably more useful here!)

Comment: I installed grc and ls was not colorized at all. 'type ls' gives '/bin/ls', nothing aliased. Back to the bash profile solution I guess.

Comment: @6005, did you install GRC with `brew`? (And did it install successfully, with no errors?) What does `brew doctor` report - any problems? What shell are you using, and have you modified the shell's config at all?You may need to edit your `.bash_profile` (or config for whatever shell you use) to source the GRC aliases. My `.bash_profile` has this (though I added it myself - my bash config is pretty esoteric...): `[ -f /usr/local/etc/grc.bashrc ] && . /usr/local/etc/grc.bashrc`

Comment: Note: for some reason  `ls` is commented out by default in the `grc.bashrc` when installed via homebrew.

Answer (score 1):

Since OP asked specifically about iTerm2:

FYI the app now has Solarized color profiles available by default!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ZSH, you can try [Oh My ZSH](https://ohmyz.sh/). If you just want to select from some pre-made themes which have sensible colors instead of manually selecting colors for all the various options for hours on end, Oh My ZSH is a good solution.  A single command to install it and it just works.

Comment: OMZ should be avoided especially by novices.  It creates more problems than it solves all for the goal of creating a CLI experience influenced by r/unixcorn.

Comment: @Allan, can you elaborate on the problems it causes?

Comment: Yes.  People complain here of all sorts of weird shell behavior, none know how to do basic shell tasks only to find that uninstalling OMZ solves the issue.  If you need a fancy prompt, you should learn how to do it manually, but by the time you learn it, you learn the fancy prompt is nothing useful.

Comment: I've had a Mac for a week now, and I just want a terminal that has basic stuff like search, themes, etc. Stuff that you would think a company with a 2.6 trillion dollar market cap would add into their SW ;)  But I guess I'll be on the lookout for the shell weirdness. So far, the only weirdness I've seen has been introduced by Apple itself via shell sessions, weird default settings for Terminal, and the code in `/etc/zsh_Apple_terminal`. Maybe you know the answer to this: https://superuser.com/questions/1782411/prevent-double-clicked-sh-script-from-being-entered-into-zsh-history-on-mac ?

Comment: You don’t need OMZ for “search”. We have tools like `find`, `locate`, and `mdfind` (same as the GUI Spotlight searches).  OMZ will not help you with any of this.  This $2.6T company is the only one making a [certified Unix](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/459469/119271).  All Linux distros are “unix like.”  Most people aren’t aware of the power behind that Terminal screen with macOS

Comment: As for your SU question, did you log out and back in or source the changed files?

Comment: When I say "search", I'm talking about text that is already displayed. `find` and the like have to be run in conjunction with the command who's output you care about piped in. Yes, OMZ doesn't help with search, had to use iterm2 for that. I couldn't care less about MacOS being Unix compliant. I'd much rather them not be hostile to developers than be Unix compliant. Hostile == requiring Apple account to DL Xcode, not allowing Xcode to run on other OS, forcing developers to have Apple HW to make iPhone app, and not having an option to bulk remap keyboard shortcuts to other common systems, etc.

Comment: Thanks for looking at that question. Yes, I logged out and logged back in after file changes.

Comment: The only response is “Their ecosystem, their rules.”