# Yellow background/black text ls output

Tags: terminal, color

Here is what I have for ls output in my Volumes dir ...

[image: ls output]

Going from the info found here ...

[What do the different colors mean in ls?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17299/what-do-the-different-colors-mean-in-ls)

it seems its "file that is setgid (g+s)".  However, I do not know what that means?  What are the implications of this?  Also, why is the other external hdd not the same?  Is there a way to change it to normal?  Also, in the second column it seems that both hdds have 24 and 23 links to them.  Is this normal?  Thank you.

Comment: First off, you are looking at the color designation for Linux, not FreeBSD/macOS.  See this relevant post:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/282189/119271  Secondly, can you execute the command `echo $LSCOLORS`  to see if anything has been customized on your end.

Answer (score 4):

Those colors indicate that you are in a *directory that's writable by others and the sticky bit isn't set*.  This is defined by the attributes in the first column: `drwxrwxrwx`

What this is telling you is that it's a directory, the user, group, and others all have read, write, and execute permissions on the file.  This would be the equivalent of issuing `chmod 777` on that directory

In the other volume (`WDred`) it has the attributes `drwxrwxr-x` which means it's a directory, the user and group have read, write and execute rights while others can only read and execute (no write permissions).  This is the equivlant of `chmod 775`.

#### Permission Attributes

The first character is is the type

```
-    regular file
d    directory
l    symbolic link
n    network file
s    socket
```

The next nine characters are the permissions for, in order by groups of three, owner, group, others

```
r    Permission to read file
w    Permission to write to file
x    Permission to execute file
a    Archive bit is on (file has not been backed up)
c    Compressed file
s    System file
h    Hidden file
t    Temporary file
```

#### Colorized output

The color you are seeing is **not** indicative of the permissions set in the system - it's a customization you control to help you identify things.

You must "ask" for colorized output with the command `ls -G` (my ls has been aliased to be `ls -laGh` meaning list, all, color, human readable).

Next and optionally, you must specify your colors in an environment variable `LSCOLORS` which would look something like this

```
export LSCOLORS="exfxcxdxcxegedabagacad"
```

Each attribute has a pair of letters; the first one being directory.  The first pair is directory foreground and directory background.  `ex` would be blue with the default background.

There's an excellent [LSCOLOR Generator](https://geoff.greer.fm/lscolors/) to see what the colors look like "live"

For a full description of what the colors are and how they are tied to attributes view the [man page for ls](https://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/1/ls/) (`man ls`) and look for the `LSCOLORS` section.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought it had something to do with permissions.  I am reading up on setuid/setgid permissions right now.  Do you think it's a good idea to have setgid permissions enabled on my external hdds?  What permissions would be the best/most safe? I think I may have changed the permissions when I was trying to set up my drives to be shared over the network through my RPi.  I had set up a samba server and the drives would show up on my mac and I could access the files, but not write to the drives.  I think in trying to gain write access I changed the permissions.  Though I'm not sure. :D

Comment: There is no "best" for permissions.  It's what works best for your scenario.  In some instances you want everyone to have access (`chmod 777`) and in other situations you only want to have the user and nobody else have to have just read/write permissions (`chmod 600`).  In some cases, like if your drive is formatted NTFS (shared with Windows) you have no choice and write permissions are defaulted to "no" for everyone.

Comment: Ok thank you.  That helped understand this a little more.  I think what I'll do it remove the setgid permission on the drive.  reading here: https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/it-security/understand-the-setuid-and-setgid-permissions-to-improve-security/ it seems there is no reason to have it set for general use

Comment: *it seems there is no reason to have it set for general use* -- Exactly.