# How can i get colored text in macOS Ventura?

Tags: macos, terminal, ventura

I've had a MacBook air for two years and today I wondered if I could put colored text in the terminal. On linux it is by default but on mac not and all the methods I have found so far do not work.

YET TRIED:

- [How do I get different colors for directories, etc. in iTerm2?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/282185/how-do-i-get-different-colors-for-directories-etc-in-iterm2)

My Hardware and Software:
OS= macOS Ventura 13.1
Hardware= MacBook Air 13" M1

Comment: The dupe uses iTerm2 instead of Terminal, but that is actually irrelevant; the problem and answer are the same regardless of the terminal app you use.

Comment: it doesn't work... yet tried!

Comment: Did you put it in `.bash_profile` or `.zprofile`?

Comment: Try this https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/396296/119271

Comment: Yes this work 

Comment: Remember to up vote what works for you sobwe know the answer is useful