# How can I change my terminal prompt name?

Tags: terminal, command-line

Recently, I changed my terminal prompt name to get rid of everything except the dollar sign. I did this a while ago, and from what I remember, I used System Preferences to make the change rather than my terminal. I want to change my name back to the default settings now, but I'm not sure how to undo this through System Preferences.

Edit:
`echo $0` gave me an output of `-zsh` and `cat ~/.zprofile | grep -i ps1` output nothing and just printed `$` on a new line.

[image: Image of my terminal window]

Comment: This isn’t a system preference (AFIK) because it can differ depending on the shell you use. You didn’t specify your macOS nor shell, so, start with this:  in Terminal, type `echo $0`. If it says “bash” or “zsh” post the output of `cat ~/.bash_profile | grep -i ps1` or  `cat ~/.zprofile | grep -i ps1`  respectively.  Be sure to do this with an [edit] to the original question

Comment: If nothing was output, see if it is set in `.zshrc`

Comment: I don't seem to have a `.zshrc` -- running `ls -a` shows `.zprofile`, `.zsh_history`, `.zsh_sessions`, and `.zshenv` but nothing else related to `.zsh`

Comment: That’s ok, many folks use `zshrc` and `zprofile` interchangeably.  It’s odd that you’re getting a `$` prompt since the `%` is used in Zsh.  Can you post the contents of `cat ~/.zprofile | pbcopy`.  It will go to your clipboard so just paste it to the question.  Format it if you can (for easy reading; see “help” on right side of AD)

Comment: Sure, here it is: `eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
`

Comment: Just that one line?

Comment: Regarding preferences, you could have used Terminal's "Settings". Under "Profiles" and the "Shell" tab, did you set some command to run (for example a command setting prompt) upon startup?

Comment: @Allan, yes, that is the only line of output I am getting.
JohnPalmieri, I can't see a "Profiles" tab, and under the "Shell" tab, there isn't any indication of a command. I'm not sure how to definitively check this, though.

Comment: What's in `.zshenv`?

Comment: `. "$HOME/.cargo/env"`

Comment: If you’ve got nothing in there, go ahead and set a prompt in `.zprofile`. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/396296/119271 for an example and reference

Comment: I added `PROMPT='%F{blue}%n%f %#'` under that first line of the `.zshenv` it didn't change anything. I still am only getting a dollar sign as my prompt, and the terminal is still black.

Comment: When you change and save your .zprofile or .zshenv or .zshrc files, or create them if they don't already exist, you'll need to exit your current shell session and start a new one to get the changes.

Comment: I don’t recommend putting your prompt in `.zshenv`.  This is for all shells - interactive and non-interactive.  There’s no point in setting a prompt in a shell you can’t interact in.  Set it in `.zprofile` instead.  See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/388623/119271) I wrote on the topic.

Comment: I tried putting `PROMPT='%F{blue}%n%f %#'` in `.zshenv` and `.zprofile` but neither of them changed anything

Comment: You can resort to basic debugging: first insert `echo "hello, this is .zshrc"` into your `.zshrc` (etc.) files. If you don't see "hello ..." when you start a new terminal window, those scripts are not getting executed. If you see them, you can add `echo $PROMPT` and `echo $PS1` into the scripts, say at the top and at the bottom, to see if anything in the scripts is changing them.

Comment: Was debugging as you mentioned and just found something. It seems that my terminal is automatically running the command `export PROMPT=" $";clear;` on startup. I only found this by pressing the up arrow immediately after starting the terminal.

It turns out that for some reason I added a command to run on terminal startup sometime in the past. I found it by clicking on "Terminal > Preferences > Shell". Everything seems to be working as intended now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that for some reason I added a command (`EXPORT PROMPT=" $"`) to run on terminal startup sometime in the past. I found it by clicking on "Terminal > Preferences > Shell". Deleting that command fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some examples of what I use at different times, in my .zshrc file:

```
PS1=" %n @%m %1~ ⚡ "
```

which gives me (when in my ~/Documents directory):

```
bw @Redwood Documents ⚡
```

Or:

```
PS1=" me here now: %1~ ⚡ "
```

which shows as:

```
me here now: Documents ⚡
```

(I use a colored lightning bolt so it's easy to spot.)

Remember to exit your current shell and start a new one to see the change. If you don't find a .zshrc file in your home directory, create it as a text file.

Comment: Just tried this -- I created a `.zshrc` and pasted in your example, but it didn't change anything

Comment: Interesting. Mine has survived moving from bash to zsh and several OS upgrades up to the latest. I assume you exited any current terminal session and started a new one, and that you put the file in your home directory. I wonder whether you have some other, perhaps older (bash , maybe?) dot-files still in play. ADDED: Oh, I see you found the problem in your Terminal settings. Good sleuthing!